# jQuery Scanner detection automatically firing enter key event

Tags: javascript, jquery, barcode-scanner

jQuery scanned delectation is automatically firing enter key event.

I do not want to call enter key method instead i want to call my another method.

```
 jQuery("#txtBatchNumber").scannerDetection({
    timeBeforeScanTest: 200,
    endChar: [13],
    avgTimeByChar: 60,        
    onComplete: function (barcodeValue) {
        jQuery("#txtBatchNumber").val();
        GetPalletInfoForLabelFromOtherSite(barcodeValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @GabrielChiHongLee i have posted my code

Comment: Have you tried to bind the selector as the documentation says? `$(selector).bind('scannerDetectionComplete',function(e,data){...})`